# HashMap of AccountId tuple and ink_storage::collections::Vec

Tags: rust, rust-ink

I want to create a `HashMap` storage item in ink!.

```
#[ink(storage)]
pub struct item {
    shipment: ink_storage::collections::HashMap<
        (AccountId, AccountId),
        ink_storage::collections::Vec<u128>,
    >,
}
```

And initialize it:

```
#[ink(constructor)]
pub fn new() -> Self {
    Self {
        shipment: ink_storage::collections::HashMap::new(),
    }
}
```

I encountered this error message

> the trait `PackedLayout` is not implemented for
> `ink_storage::Vec

Comment: From their docs it seems this trait is implemented for [`Vec` from standard library](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_storage/traits/trait.PackedLayout.html#impl-PackedLayout-for-Vec%3CT%3E)

Answer (score 0):

`ink_storage::Vec` does not implement `PackedLayout` because its layout is not packed! According to [the docs](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_storage/struct.Vec.html):

> Despite the similarity to Rust’s `Vec` type this storage `Vec` has many differences in its internal data layout. While it stores its data in contiguous storage slots this does not mean that the data is actually densely stored in memory.

The data is organised in contiguous chunks, but each chunk may not be adjacent to the previous in memory.

On the other hand, `std::vec::Vec` *does* implement `PackedLayout`, so you should be able to use that instead.

Comment: how will i initialize the HashMap after changing to std::vec::Vec?